# How to stop jobs scheduled using spring task

Tags: java, spring

I have implemented a sample spring scheduled task, with an applicationContext as follows,

```
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="myScheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="cron" method="show" cron="0/10 * * * * ?"/>
    <task:scheduled ref="cron" method="show2" cron="0/15 * * * * ?"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>

<task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="10"/>
```

How can I stop this schedule method?

Answer (score 3):

Inject the `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` into another bean, and invoke `shutdown()`.  If that isn't acceptable, you could configure the `cron` bean to accept a flag.  For example:

```
public class Job() {
    private final AtomicBoolean stop = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    public void show() {
        if (stop.get()) {
            return;
        }
        ...
    }

    public void stop() {
        stop.set(true);
    }
}
```

Note that this won't remove the job from the scheduler.  The only way to prevent that would be to obtain a reference to the `ScheduledFuture` and call `cancel()`.

Comment: Hmm, Could you write me an example method which will be stop my taks schedule method show()?

Comment: OK, so How can I remove the job from the scheduler? Could give me an axample?

Comment: Obtain a reference to the job, and call cancel.  I added this in my answer already.

Comment: How can I do a reference to the job?

Comment: You have to manually add to the `TaskScheduler`, i.e. not using Spring config.

Comment: For example in xml file next method which will stop job?

Comment: No, you *can't* stop it from the XML file.  That wouldn't make sense.

Comment: So I don't understand. Where in my application I must do it?

Comment: Inject `myScheduler` into another bean, and do it in that bean's `init-method`.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean by "stop".

1. **Business Condition Stop:**
   Stop as result of a business condition, you should have those conditions evaluated in your methods and just simply not execute the code. This way you can stop unwanted execution at runtime, run your logic to handle the condition fail (logging,notification,etc) as a result.
2. **Non Business Condition:**
   Externalize the chron expression to properties file or as I prefer a system variable in the JVM. Then you can just change the property value to a 9999 scenario to stop any execution.

**System Variable Example.**

```
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="myScheduler">
<task:scheduled ref="cron" method="show" cron="#{systemProperties['chron1']}"/>
<task:scheduled ref="cron" method="show2" cron="#{systemProperties['chron2']}"/>
```